# JavaMailSender - NoClassDefFoundError on jakarta/mail/Transport while sending email

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send an email with JavaMailSender but I get a NoClassDefFoundError on jakarta/mail/Transport.

The full stacktrace : https://pastebin.com/eCNHpxT5

The pom : https://pastebin.com/jC6nfuRu

The parent pom : https://pastebin.com/jADMpZeF

My conf

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender emailSender(final MailProperties mailProperties) {
    final JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSenderImpl = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    javaMailSenderImpl.setHost(mailProperties.getHost());
    javaMailSenderImpl.setPort(mailProperties.getPort());
    Properties props = javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    return javaMailSenderImpl;
}
```

and then I try to send like this

```
private final JavaMailSender emailSender;

@Autowired
public MailBuildService(final JavaMailSender emailSender) {
    this.emailSender = emailSender;
}

final MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
final MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "UTF-8");
helper.setFrom(senderMail, senderName);
helper.setTo(recipient);
helper.setSubject(mailSubject);
helper.setText(mail.getTextContent(), mail.getHtmlContent());
emailSender.send(message);
```

Comment: quite likely you have some inconsistent spring lib version, could you include your pom.xml and the full stacktrace of NoClassDefFoundError?

Comment: You can also send mails using javax.mail check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76758716/how-can-i-make-it-possible-to-automatically-authenticate-when-sending-an-email-t/76762709#76762709)

Comment: @samabcde i edit my message with the pom and the full stack trace

Comment: I tried your solution @Eric but I got a smiliar exception (this time, it's jakarta/activation/DataContentHandler that is not found)
I definitely got something wrong in my pom

Comment: I can't reproduce your error using the pom given, what I can suggest is to put a break point in `javax.mail.Session`L492, and see why provider return a class name `jakarta.mail.Transport`

Comment: Have you tried to clean & build project before running it. Sometimes dependencies/libraries aren't added successfully until clean & build is done first